# Need help interpreting question about convex combinations..

Tags: optimization, convex-optimization, linear-programming

The question states:

Suppose $x_{1}, x_{2}, ..., x_{k}$ are $k$ points in $\mathbb{R}^n$. Show that the set of all convex combinations of these points,

$$C=\{\sum\limits_{i=1}^{k} c_{i}x_{i} \mid \sum\limits_{i=1}^{i=k} c_{i}=1, c_{i} \geq 0 \text{ for all } i=1,2,...,k \}, $$

is a convex subset of $\mathbb{R}^n$.

Comment: I know I have to show that there is an interval amongst these points or something along those lines which would show a convex combination...

Comment: Can you help me understand what the set $C$ is... or maybe how to expand it?

Comment: I  understand what a convex set is.. essentially it is a line interval that falls within a given functions constraints... but how do I show a line interval given this type of set description? @Magnusseen

Comment: I am new to linear programming/optimization

Comment: As you mentioned, $C$ is the set of all convex combinations of the $x_k$'s. For a geometrical representation, imagine the $x_k$'s are three points in the plane which are not on a line; then $C$ is exactly the triangle with those vertices

Comment: Sure, I understand that.. now how would I show that this is a convex set, without being given any functions or constraints or anything?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $y_1,y_2\in C$ and $\alpha \in (0,1).$ Hence there exists $c_1\ldots,c_k, p_1,\ldots,p_k\geq 0$ such that $$\sum_{i=1}^kc_i=\sum_{i=1}^kp_i=1$$ and

$$y_1=\sum_{i=1}^kc_i x_i,\; y_2=\sum_{i=1}^kp_i x_i.$$ Now

$$\alpha y_1+(1-\alpha)y_2= \alpha \sum_{i=1}^kc_i x_i +(1-\alpha) \sum_{i=1}^kp_i x_i$$ 
$$= \sum_{i=1}^k (\alpha c_i +(1-\alpha)p_i) x_i.$$ Now note that $q_i=\alpha c_i +(1-\alpha)p_i\geq 0$ and sum up to 1.

Comment: Dumb question: $a$ can be interpreted the same way as $\lambda$ would, correct?

Comment: yes, that is correct